# How to check in array if it contains given element

Tags: javascript

I am trying below code but its not working so first am trying to get a person department Name currently, hard coded it to check

```
var arr=[]
let CurrDept = "AB-CDE-F";
var Detept=CurrDept.substring(0,5);
arr.push(Detept)
```

Now in below line of code i am trying this line so it should exclude all results which start from `AB-CD`

```
var Userprofiledept=data.value[0].UserId.Department;
const isInArray = arr.indexOf(Userprofiledept) > -1;
```

`isInArray` should be false which can be put in my condition but it always give true

Can anyone help ?

So current user department may be `AB-CDE-F` and data i am getting from my rest call may have lots of department for many users `AB-CDE-F,AB-CDE-F,AB-CDE,AB-CD,AB-C`

so only want to exclude results which are `AB-CDE-F,AB-CDE-F,AB-CDE,AB-CD` as they are starting with `AB-CD`

Comment: What is `data.value[0].UserId.Department;`?

Comment: its department name which i am getting from my rest call so it can be like "AB-CDE-F","AB-CDE","AB-CD" or  AB-C" so i want to exclude all result which have AB-CD

Comment: Well your `indexOf` test is testing to see if the supplied string IS in the array and since you want to exclude such strings, you should be checking for `===-1` instead.

Comment: do you have some examples with wanted result?

Comment: yes let me modify my question

Comment: Can't you use `data.value[0].UserId.Department.substr(0, 5)` just like when you add to `arr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [String.prototype.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

```js
const 
  data = {value: [{ UserId: { ID: 14, Email: "sdfds", Department: "AB-CD-EF" } }, { UserId: { ID: 14, Email: "sdfds", Department: "AB-CD" } }, { UserId: { ID: 14, Email: "sdfds", Department: "AB-C" } }]},
  discard = "AB-CD",
  res = data.value.filter((v) => !v.UserId.Department.startsWith(discard));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I have this array from my api call how shall i write filter on this?
{'value':[{"UserId":{"ID":14,"Email":"sdfds","Department":"AB-CD-EF"}},{"UserId":{"ID":14,"Email":"sdfds","Department":"AB-CD"}},{"UserId":{"ID":14,"Email":"sdfds","Department":"AB-C"}}]}

Comment: @Ashok I've updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the functionality into a function and check if the substring exists and add, if necessary.

```js
const
    add = string => {
        string = string.slice(0, 5);
        if (array.includes(string)) return;
        array.push(string);
    }
    array = [];

add('AB-CDE-F');
console.log(array);

add('AB-CDE-F');
console.log(array);

add('AB-CDE');
console.log(array);
```